# Nginx Is it ok to not to set server_name?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to test the server before deploying a docker image.

If I have `server_name` set in nginx, When I test, it redirects to the url specified in the `server_name` and I don't want that happen.

Also I need to have redirection rule such as

```
server {

     server_name www.example.kr;
     return 301 $scheme://example.kr$request_uri;
}
```

So How do I make the test server not to redirect to the real `www.example.com` and also have `www.example.com` to redirect to `example.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an IF checking hostname and redirecting it to real server, then comment out server_name block and use it as default server (not sure it could make sense as dns could or should be different between test and production server)

Configuration could be like

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }     
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    #server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
    .. your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, just commenting that even when this is a valid and working answer, in nginx best practices, it's better to limit the "if" used: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/  But this is a perfect valid and working answer.